# Differentiate a Function with respect to a different function.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Suppose you have two functions $f(t)$ and $g(t)$.

How would you generally differentiate for any real valued functions: $\frac{df}{dg}$?

And also a specific case:

$$f(t) = t^3 + t^2 + 1 $$
$$g(t) = (t^2 + 1)^4 + t^3$$

Comment: $\frac{df}{dg} = \frac{df}{dt}(\frac{dg}{dt})^{-1}$

Comment: Note that the chain rule applies if $f$ is a function of $g$ - i.e. given a value of $g$ there is a well-defined value of $f$ associated with it. That is not always completely obvious when parametric definitions are given. For example, if a smooth curve given by parameters crosses itself there are two potential tangents/gradients at the crossing point. These may be distinguished by the value of $t$, but not by the value of $g$.

Comment: @AmourK I answered your question for both the general case for which $\frac{dg}{dt}\ne0$ and the specific case for which you provided parametric equations.  Please let me know if there is anything that I can add.  I would like to give my best answer to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{df}{dg}=\frac{\frac{df}{dt}}{\frac{dg}{dt}}$ from the chain rule.  Here,

$$\frac{df}{dt}=3t^2+2t$$

$$\frac{dg}{dt}=8t(t^2+1)^3+3t^2$$

So,

$$\frac{df}{dg}=\frac{\frac{df}{dt}}{\frac{dg}{dt}}=\frac{3t^2+2t}{8t(t^2+1)^3+3t^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

For the general case, use the chain rule:

$$\frac{df}{dg}=\frac{\frac{df}{dt}}{\frac{dg}{dt}}$$

or perhaps better formatted as

$$\frac{df}{dg}=\frac{df}{dt}/\frac{dg}{dt}$$

This kind of calculation is common when working with parametric equations, which seems to be the case for you.

For the specific case, can't you do the derivatives of $f$ and $g$?

Comment: I wasn't aware that the chain rule could be written as a quotient as well. I guess it kind of makes sense if you think as the derivative as a fraction. Thanks.

Comment: @AmourK There is an additional factor to take into account - see my comment on your question. You need to know you are dealing with a function.

Comment: @MarkBennet: I assumed that the questioner is paraphrasing a question about parametric equations, getting the question slightly wrong. My answer applies well to the assumed actual question: your comment applies well to the actual question written here. Only the OP could say which is the case.

Comment: @RoryDaulton No quarrel. Just want to make sure people are appropriately alert!